# generate random numbers truncated to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, random, numpy

I would like to generate uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 0.5, but truncated to 2 decimal places.

without the truncation, I know this is done by

```
import numpy as np
rs = np.random.RandomState(123456)
set = rs.uniform(size=(50,1))*0.5
```

could anyone help me with suggestions on how to generate random numbers up to 2 d.p. only? Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that decimal `0.1` *doesn't exist* as a `float`?

Comment: yes, i believe i should have clarified that i wanted it rounded off to 2 significant figures. (within numerical precision)

Comment: @mtigger: I think you're missing the point. If you round `0.10` to 2 significant figures and store it in a `float` (or numpy `f8`), you get `0.100000000000000005551115`. And the next smaller `float` is less than `0.10`. There is no value equal to `0.10` in IEEE double.

Comment: @mtigger: Well, that's *impossible*. `0.10` can *not* be stored in a `float`. It will always be an approximation. In Python 2.6, you can see this (in higher versions it's hidden but still there): Type `.1` at the prompt and see that it's represented as `0.10000000000000001` (which is still just an approximation).

Comment: In 2.7 or 3.x, just type `'{:.24}'.format(0.1)` and you can still see it.

Comment: Generate random integers and interpret them with an implicit shift of 100. Or use a decimal data type.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The fixed-point suggestion is a great idea. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `float` cannot be truncated (or rounded) to 2 decimal digits, because there are many values with 2 decimal digits that just cannot be represented exactly as an IEEE double.

If you really want what you say you want, you need to use a type with exact precision, like [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Of course there are downsides to doing that—the most obvious one for `numpy` users being that you will have to use `dtype=object`, with all of the compactness and performance implications.

But it's the only way to actually do what you asked for.

Most likely, what you actually *want* to do is either Joran Beasley's answer (leave them untruncated, and just round at print-out time) or something similar to Lauritz V. Thaulow's answer (get the closest approximation you can, then use explicit epsilon checks everywhere).

Alternatively, you can do implicitly fixed-point arithmetic, as David Heffernan suggests in a comment: Generate random integers between 0 and 50, keep them as integers within `numpy`, and just format them as fixed point decimals and/or convert to `Decimal` when necessary (e.g., for printing results). This gives you all of the advantages of `Decimal` without the costs… although it does open an obvious window to create new bugs by forgetting to shift 2 places somewhere.

Comment: thank you, this cleared up some misconceptions I had about floats and decimals.

Comment: @mtigger: Here's the obligatory link to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 3):

decimals are not truncated to 2 decimal places ever ... however their string representation maybe

```
import numpy as np
rs = np.random.RandomState(123456)
set = rs.uniform(size=(50,1))*0.5

print ["%0.2d"%val for val in set]
```

Comment: `Decimal`s _can be_ truncated to 2 decimal places; it's `float`s that can't.

Comment: meh semantics :P (but yeah I know Decimal is an exact representation type :P)

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(50,1)).astype("float") / 100
```

That is, create random integers between 0 and 50, and divide by 100.

**EDIT:**

As made clear in the comments, this will not give you *exact* two-digit decimals to work with, due to the nature of float representations in memory. It may look like you have the exact float `0.1` in your array, but it definitely *isn't* exactly `0.1`. But it *is* very very close, and you can get it closer by using a "double" datatype instead.

You can postpone this problem by just keeping the numbers as integers, and remember that they're to be divided by 100 when you use them.

```
hundreds = random.randint(0, 50, size=(50, 1))
```

Then at least the roundoff won't happen until at the last minute (or maybe not at all, if the numerator of the equation is a multiple of the denominator).

Comment: @Joran Wow, that's fast feedback. Have you tested this? My tests all return only two or one decimal places.

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow: There are many values with two decimal places that cannot be represented exactly as a float (IEEE double). So, you may get the closest float to the value you wanted, and it may even `repr` and `str` as the value you wanted… but when you do arithmetic with it, or just compare it with `==`, it may not be the value you wanted. You have to use an exact-precision type like `Decimal` if you really want two decimal places.

Comment: Also, this doesn't solve the problem because sampling from a normal distribute won't generate integers (though you could round the distribution so it does).  A more general idea of a solution along these lines would be (for x~Norm(params)), `int(round(x*100))/100`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find another alternative:

```
import numpy as np
rs = np.random.RandomState(123456)
set = rs.uniform(size=(50,2))
for i in range(50):
    for j in range(2):
        set[i,j] = round(set[i,j],2)
```

Comment: Why not just use `np.around(rs.uniform(size=(50,2)) * 0.5, decimals=2)` then? It's faster, it works the same, and has the same technical drawback that my solution has, as noted in [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around): *Results may also be surprising due to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point standard*.